# TYPO3 renders header as h2 not as h1

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

My TYPO3 ver.: 7 renders the content element header as `h2` and not as `h1` ... how can I solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the options of the Type drop down?!

Comment: can you please look up the second screen I've added, thats the problem there the default header is set to 2 ... how can i change this?

Comment: TYPO3 does exactly what you want. Default settings is H1 so you changed it and now you are surprised?

Comment: I haven't made this change. Its a clean install no Plugins Yet....

Comment: Ach! you're right (sorry for blaming you) `fluid_styled_content` introduces that... Wellp, that among with several other things indicates that this ext is not production-ready yet :/

Comment: no problem ;) now it works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The typoscript you showed sets the default header level to 2 aka `<h2>...</h2>`

```
styles.content.defaultHeaderType = 2
```

You can change this behavior by changing that value via typoscript

```
styles.content.defaultHeaderType = 1
```

This setting needs to be done in the **constants** field of a typoscript template.

A little more information can be found at https://buzz.typo3.org/people/ron-hall/article/changing-the-default-header-for-content-elements/

Comment: Note: by default  `defaultHeaderType = 1` in TYPO3 (since forever) `fluid_styled_content` ext forces `2` that's invalid IMHO...

Comment: IMHO it's not invalid or broken. fluid_styled_content (FSC) does not aim to be a 100% compatible extension which generates the same output as css_styled_content (CSC). FSC is way cleaner than CSC. You will also recognize that a lot of database fields are gone, when only using FSC. SEO-wise it's a good idea to not allow setting <h1> headlines by the editor. There should only be one <h1> headline per page. This main headline could for example be generated automatically based on the page title. But this is not part of the problem discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Bootstrap-Package, goto:
Templates > Constant Editor > BOOTSTRAP PACKAGE: CONTENT ELEMENTS > Header

Edit the following constant:
plugin.bootstrap_package_contentelements.header.defaultHeaderType = 1